# Is it possible to get a resource from a feature?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I can access a resource in a plugin

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID);
URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("resources/resource.txt");
```

Is it possible to do something similar using a feature?

Comment: Not that I know off. Outside of the install code there aren't really any APIs for features.

Comment: Features are just bundles, so as long as you know the bundle ID, you should be able te get a reference and access entries.

Comment: @emilles Features are not bundles. Quite often a feature has a plugin/Bundle with the same id - usually the 'branding' plugin.